# Xamarin iOS: Kill off async event handlers when a view controller is removed from the navigation stack

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, uinavigationcontroller

My `RootViewController` is a `UINavigationController`. The navigation stack starts with `ViewController` which then pushes `CustomViewController`.

```
public class ViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad ()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad ();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;

        NavigationController.PushViewController(new CustomViewController(), true);
    }
}

public class CustomViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.DarkGray;

        var button = new UIButton
        {
            TranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        };

        View.AddSubview(button);

        button.SetTitle("Click me", UIControlState.Normal);

        button.WidthAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(250).Active = true;
        button.HeightAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(50).Active = true;
        button.CenterXAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.CenterXAnchor).Active = true;
        button.CenterYAnchor.ConstraintEqualTo(View.CenterYAnchor).Active = true;

        button.AddTarget(async (sender, e) => 
        {
            await Task.Delay(3000);
            NavigationController.PushViewController(new CustomViewController(), true);
        }, UIControlEvent.TouchUpInside);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having is when the user clicks the button and pops its containing view controller immediately afterwards, the async event handler keeps running. After 3 seconds, it will attempt to push the same view controller, but `NavigationController` is set to null.

**When a page is dismissed / popped off the stack, is there a way to cancel all running async methods?** Note that my actual use case involves more complex interactions. I tried using a `CancellationToken` (`ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`) which helps with REST calls, but it is still possible that the user might go back to the previous page after the API call is done and before the async handler finishes.

I'm trying to find a generic solution to this because my app will eventually have dozens of async event handlers.

Comment: Did you have considered ``DispatchWorkItem``? It is a cancelable block.

Comment: Sounds like this will not be an option. See https://betterprogramming.pub/a-deep-dive-into-dispatchworkitem-274548357dea (specifically the part where it says "It lets us cancel an enqueued task, however, we can cancel the task only before it reaches the head of a queue and starts executing.")

Comment: I doubt iOS maintains an association from viewcontroller to running asyncs. You’ll have to invent a mechanism. Put code at start of each one that adds it to a list of cancellable tasks on viewcontroller?

Comment: As I mentioned, in my actual code, I'm passing a `CancellationToken` to HTTP calls and canceling it when a page is being popped. It seems to work, but my concern was about what happens after a REST call returns and the user pops the page before the handler finishes. Any UI work is likely to error out. For now, I'm wrapping everything in a try catch block and checking if the `NavigationController` property is null. Wish there was a better way.

Comment: *"Any UI work is likely to error out"* - If you **wrap the entire action in a cancellable task**, then add that cancellable task to a list, then you can cancel the tasks on that list (thereby cancelling any child tasks that were started) at any time. Am I missing something? `button.AddTarget( async () => MyMethodToCreateCancellableTaskAndAddToControllersList(() => { ... } );`

Comment: ... Pondering the implications of your question, I'm wondering whether *all* async/await code should be wrapped at the top-level in try-catch. I can think of other situations that would cause the assumptions of code to no longer be valid, upon *any* return from an `await`, at *any* depth in the call stack. (Code that only works with local state would be fine.) Perhaps its easiest/safest to assume all async code might fail occasionally.